# How to slice multiple bounding boxes from PyTorch Tensor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, slice, bounding-box

So my question is fairly simple one:

- I have multiple bounding boxes formed by: `[TopLeft_X, TopLeft_Y,
  BottomRight_X, BottomRight_Y]`
- And also I have a Tensor mask sized `[900,
  1600]`
- So here is the first 3 bounding boxes I have:

  `tensor([[1041,  465, 1102,  508],
          [1037,  468, 1108,  519],
          [1041,  465, 1107,  515]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.int32)`
- Essentially, I want to get number of pixels(valued as 1) that each
  bounding box intersects with mask.
- Currently, I am looping through all the bounding boxes and get the
  respective slicing as:

  map_mask[y_min:y_max, x_min:x_max] -> 2D Output

How can I do this simultaneously without a for loop in PyTorch?